# Interacting with the FileSystem using TypeScript Path Aliases

Tags: node.js, typescript, filesystems, filenames, tsconfig

I'm working in a rather large monorepo, so I set up some [path aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
  "@app/specialLib/*": ["libs/specialLib/src/lib/*"],
  "@app/specialLib": ["libs/specialLib/src/index.ts"],
}
```

so that I can simplify my import statements, both in my apps, and in other places inside the library:

```js
import { Foo } from "@app/specialLib"
import { SubItem } from "@app/specialLib/nested/library"
```

In one of my library files, I need to work with the file system, using [writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options):

```js
// the path to the log file
const itemLog = "@app/specialLib/item-log.json";

// remove the necessary item from the log
let loggedItems: LogItem[] = require(itemLog);
loggedItems = loggedItems.filter(({ id }) => {
    id != this.id;
});

// write the log back to the file system
writeFileSync(resolve(itemLog), JSON.stringify(loggedItems));
```

Now the compiler can resolve the `require` just fine, but when I try to run my script, I get `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Chris\development\Big.Monorepo\@app\specialLib\item-log.json'`, because of course, there is no such folder on my machine. I've tried just using the variable itself, as well as wrapping it inside of [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths), with the same effects.

So my question is this: is there a way to read and write to the file system using Node's built-in functionality in conjunction with TypeScript path aliases?